# Java JAXB XJC code generation form XSD schema problem

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have my own domain model and corresponding XSD schema for it. It consists of data types and messages that are exchanged in my application. I use XJC tool from Java JRE 1.5 for generation of Java classes for the given XSD schema. The generated classes do not contain neither the serialization/deserialization method nor the validation code. How can I achieve this using JAXB?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Are you using JAXB 1.x or 2.x?

If 2.x then validation is built in. See this [article](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-architecture-for-xml-binding/what-is-new-in-jaxb-2.0.html).

Do you mean that you just want the code to marshall the Bean to XML and  unmarshall the XML to a Bean?

There are many [articles](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_jaxbmarshalxml.html) that show this. Here's an example of marshalling a bean into xml:

```
JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyBean.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxb.createMarshaller();
java.io.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(myBean, sw);
System.out.println(sw.toString());
```